# difference between printing strings with & and with out &

Tags: c

```
  #include<stdio.h>

   int main()
   {
       char str[25] = "helloworld";
       printf("%s %s", &str+2,str+2);
       return 0;
   }
```

What is the difference between &str+2 and str+2 here as str=&str. please help me.

thanks

Comment: `&str` and `str` *are not* the same thing. They have the same address, but *different type*.

Comment: can you please share some more information.thanks..

Comment: They don't have the same address. `str` is a pointer to an array of characters representing the string. `&str` is a pointer to the memory location that stores the value of `str`

Comment: @user1632141: `&str` is the address of an array, and `str` is the same as `&str[0]`, which is the address of the *first element* of the array. It's like pointing at the Statue of Liberty and claiming that you've proved that New York and the United States of America are the same thing, because you're pointing at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you have an array: `str[xxx]`
`str` give you the memory address of the beginning of the array so `str+2` would point to `"lloworld"`.
`&str` gives you *the address where str is stored*. So by printing &str+2 you an have unexpected behaviors.

Answer (score 2):

`&` gets the address of that variable, not the value that the variable points to. However, with an array of chars, the value will be the start of that array (first slot).

`&str+2` gets the memory location of `str` and adds `2`.

`str+2` gets the memory location of the start and adds 2 bytes (`char` = 1 byte, look into pointer arithmetic).

Comment: so does &str+2 mean adding 4bytes to the value of &str considering we are adding an int value to &str?please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @user1632141 It means get address of the start of the string's address (address of a pointer) and add 2.

Answer (score 1):

&str+2  gives atually address but here in printf statement we are using %s so it's giving output a garbage value and for str+2 the output will be llworld

check this link for output compile several times and see what's the output we are getting

http://codepad.org/vODzmZj3

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else, `&str` (and thus `&str+2`) has the wrong type to pass to `printf` for the `%s` specifier. It requires `char *` (pointer to `char`), and `&str` has type `char (*)[25]` (pointer to array of 25 `char`s). Passing the wrong type to `printf` invokes undefined behavior.

Moreover, `&str` points to an array of length 1 (its elements are arrays of `char` of length 25, and there is only one of them), so `&str+2` is out-of-bounds pointer arithmetic and thus undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`&str` print the address of vailabel like '9' or in hex '0x009'

`str+2` will print `lloworld` , here +2 is as increment value

Answer (score 0):

str + 2 is the pointer to string's 3rd symbol, &str + 2 is the pointer to pointer to string plus 2

Answer (score 0):

str is the pointer to character (first character in the array). 
&str is the pointer to the character array.

When we perform the operation str+2, 2 bytes are incremented. (as its a char pointer essentially). 
When we perform the operation &str+2, 22 bytes are incremented. (as the character array is 11 bytes in length).

This is the only difference.

Regards,
Nagaraj

Answer (score -2):

You can try the following code for a reference!

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{      
    char str1[11] = "1111111111";
    char str2[11] = "2222222222";  
    char str[11]  = "helloworld";
    char str3[11] = "3333333333";
    char str4[11] = "4444444444";

   printf("%s %s\n", &str-2,str+2);
   return 0;
}
```